# How to avoid impression bias when calculate the ctr?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, ads

When we train a  ctr(click through rate) model,  sometimes we need calcute the real ctr from the history data, like this

```
                 #(click)
    ctr   =  ----------------
              #(impressions)
```

We know that, if the number of impressions is too small, the calculted ctr is not real. So we always set a threshold to filter out the large enough impressions.

But we know that the higher impressions, the higher confidence for the ctr. Then my question is that: Is there a impressions-normalized statistic method to calculate the ctr?

Thanks!

Comment: did you get how to normalize the clicks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably need a representation of confidence interval for your estimated ctr. [Wilson score interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval) is a good one to try.

[image: Wilson score interval]

You need below stats to calculate the confidence score:

- `\hat p` is the observed ctr (fraction of #clicked vs #impressions)
- `n` is the total number of impressions
- `z`<sub>α/2</sub> is the `(1-α/2)` quantile of the standard normal distribution

A simple implementation in python is shown below, I use `z`<sub>(1-α/2)</sub>=1.96 which corresponds to a 95% confidence interval. I attached 3 test results at the end of the code.

```
# clicks      # impressions       # conf interval
2             10                  (0.07, 0.45)
20            100                 (0.14, 0.27)
200           1000                (0.18, 0.22)
```

Now you can set up some threshold to use the calculated confidence interval.

```
from math import sqrt

def confidence(clicks, impressions):
    n = impressions
    if n == 0: return 0
    z = 1.96 #1.96 -> 95% confidence
    phat = float(clicks) / n
    denorm = 1. + (z*z/n)
    enum1 = phat + z*z/(2*n)
    enum2 = z * sqrt(phat*(1-phat)/n + z*z/(4*n*n))
    return (enum1-enum2)/denorm, (enum1+enum2)/denorm

def wilson(clicks, impressions):
    if impressions == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return confidence(clicks, impressions)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print wilson(2,10)
    print wilson(20,100)
    print wilson(200,1000)

"""    
--------------------
results:
(0.07048879557839793, 0.4518041980521754)
(0.14384999046998084, 0.27112660859398174)
(0.1805388068716823, 0.22099327100894336)
"""
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to know if there is a impressions-normalized statistic method, not the confidence for the estimated ctr. For example, this method may looks like this: #(click)*2/(#(impressions)+avg(#impressions))

Comment: Actually I am not sure I understand what you want and why you want that way. How about a Bayesian estimator? Or something like the IMDB score? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator

Comment: Doesn't z = 1.6 corresponds to 90% confidence? Google helper: https://www.google.ru/search?q=z+values+confidence, article for dummies :-): http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/finding-appropriate-zvalues-for-given-confidence-l.html

Comment: You are right. Should be 1.96 for 95% confidence.fixed.

Answer (score 9):

If you treat this as a binomial parameter, you can do Bayesian estimation. If your prior on ctr is uniform (a Beta distribution with parameters (1,1)) then your posterior is Beta(1+#click, 1+#impressions-#click). Your posterior mean is #click+1 / #impressions+2 if you want a single summary statistic of this posterior, but you probably don't, and here's why:

I don't know what your method for determining whether ctr is high enough, but let's say you're interested in everything with ctr > 0.9. You can then use the cumulative density function of the beta distribution to look at what proportion of probability mass is over the 0.9 threshold (this will just be 1 - the cdf at 0.9). In this way, your threshold will naturally incorporate uncertainty about the estimate because of limited sample size.

Comment: is there a way to combine this with the Wilson score, to calculate estimates where the #impressions is very low?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to calculate this confidence interval. An alternative to the Wilson Score is the Clopper-Perrson interval, which I found useful in spreadsheets.

[Upper Bound Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjwPw.png)

[Lower Bound Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqY8I.png)

Where

- `B()` is the the Inverse Beta Distribution
- `alpha` is the confidence level error (e.g for 95% confidence-level, alpha is 5%)
- `n` is the number of samples (e.g. impressions)
- `x` is the number of successes (e.g. clicks)

In Excel an implementation for `B()` is provided by the `BETA.INV` formula.

There is no equivalent formula for B() in Google Sheets, but a Google Apps Script custom function can be adapted from the JavaScript Statistical Library (e.g search github for jstat)